# Recuperar a containsKey()

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Boa tarde,

Estou começando a usar o Android Studio, na seguinte situação estou parado: tem a MainActivity onde através de um recyclerView tenho uma listagem, ao clicar em uma dessas listagens passo como parâmetro para a página 2 tal item clicado e usuario logado, porem dentro da página 2 tenho outro recyclerView que abre outras informações em uma página 3. O app para quando tento voltar para a página 2 porque os parametros que vieram da MainActivity não existem mais.

MainActivity - Onde passo os parametros para a página 2:

```
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                            Carona carona = listaCaronas.get(position);
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CorridaActivity.class );
                            i.putExtra("carona", carona );
                            i.putExtra("usuario", usuario );
                            startActivity( i );
                        }
```

Página 2 - Onde tem os dados do item clicado e o outro recycler:

```
//Recupera dados do usuário
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if( extras != null ){
        if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("carona")
                && getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("usuario")) {
            usuario = (Usuario) extras.getSerializable("usuario");
            carona = (Carona) extras.getSerializable("carona");
            //verificaStatusRequisicao();
        }
    }
```

Ou seja, quando volto da página 3 para a 2 não existe mais as containsKey("carona") e containsKey("usuario").

Comment: Talvez para resolver esse seu problema a melhor forma seria armazenar a informação da variável para acesso. Isso pode ser feito via SQLite, SharedPreferences ou uma variável de escopo global

Answer (score 0):

Devo primeiro dizer que não sou perito em android e não tenho certezas sobre quando um Intent é criado. Imagino que seja possível que ao retornar da outra actividade (página 3), o intent da página 2 seja substituído por um intent que represente esse retorno.

Se for este o caso pode tentar guardar os dados que são passados pela página 1 numa variável de instância da página 2 na criação dessa actividade (método onCreate() imagino). Desse modo, ao voltar da página 3, pode aceder a essa variável e não ao Intent da actividade.

Espero que seja útil.